# ORA-26041: DATETIME/INTERVAL datatype conversion error

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, sql-loader

I'm trying to load data in to a database using SQL-Loader but I'm (as many others) having a problem with my time format. Due to my limited skills with SQL-Loader I've not been able to find a previous post that would aid me. So here goes.

The data that I'm trying to insert is:

```
"some text"|"some text"|"some text"|"23-APR-12 12.00.00.000000000 AM"|"some text"|"some text."|"TEXT"|"23-APR-12 12.00.00.000000000 AM"|"some text"|"some text"|"some text"|"some text"|0|
```

The CTL file looks like this:

```
OPTIONS (ERRORS=1586)
LOAD DATA 
INFILE 'SOURCE.ldr' "str '{EOL}'"
APPEND
CONTINUEIF NEXT(1:1) = '#'
INTO TABLE "DATABASE_NAME"."TABLE"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY'|'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' AND '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS ( 
"DOMAIN" ,
"CONTEXT" ,
"KEY" ,
"CREATED" TIMESTAMP "DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM" ,
"DESCRIPTION" ,
"VALUE" ,
"TYPE" ,
"CHANGED" TIMESTAMP "DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM" ,
"CORPORATEENGLISHVALUE" ,
"CORPORATEVALUE" ,
"ENGLISHVALUE" ,
"OLDDBKEY" ,
"FAVOURITE" )
```

And the Table:

```
DOMAIN                  VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)
CONTEXT                 VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)
KEY                     VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)
CREATED                 TIMESTAMP(6)
DESCRIPTION             VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)
VALUE                   VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE)
TYPE                    VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)
CHANGED                 TIMESTAMP(6)
CORPORATEENGLISHVALUE   VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)
CORPORATEVALUE          VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)
ENGLISHVALUE            VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)
OLDDBKEY                VARCHAR2(35 BYTE)
FAVOURITE               NUMBER(1,0)
```

And the Oracle database has these NLS:

```
Date Format:         RRRR-MM-DD
Timestamp Format:    RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSXFF
Timestamp TZ Format: RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Record 1: Rejected - Error on table "DATABASE_NAME"."TABLE", column "CREATED".
ORA-26041: DATETIME/INTERVAL datatype conversion error
```

If I manually modify the timestamp from `23-APR-12 12.00.00.000000000 AM` to `23-APR-12 12.00.00 AM` it works fine. So my guess is that there's something wrong with the `"CREATED" TIMESTAMP "DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM"`. 
I noticed as well that there are errors with the same ORA-26041 when months are displayed different. In English October is show as `OCT`and in Swedish its `OKT`. If I manually change all English versions of the months in the data file, the script works.

Comment: Works for me if `created` and `changed` are `timestamp` columns. Can you add your table creation DDL to the question, or at least show what the datatype is for those columns?

Comment: Googling earlier I noticed a potential problem like this that could be overcome by setting `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` to `ENGLISH` in your environment before running `sqlldr`. I hadn't realised you might not be using an English locale (despite your name; I guess your English and using `Apr` threw me!). Can you try that, and I'll try to find that link again...

Comment: Previous comment was based on [this note](http://support.sas.com/kb/43/761.html). I didn't see this on the Oracle support site. So, worth a try maybe, but not making any promises *8-)

Comment: I tried that @AlexPoole and it did not work for me. I'm still having problems with it. `Record 1: Rejected - Error on table "DATABASE"."TABLE", column "CREATED".
ORA-26041: DATETIME/INTERVAL datatype conversion error`
That's the error I get.

Comment: OK, guess it was worth trying, but I think you'll have to do what the error message description in the documentation says, and contact Oracle Support. Sorry.

Comment: @AlexPoole you were right. please see my answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'll give @AlexPoole cred for this. He pointed me in the right way.

I'm sitting on a windows computer and the example was from Linux. The correct input is:

```
set NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN
```

Please bear in mind that you can't have any white space in the `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN`. I did an settings export from the target database to see what NLS settings it used so I could replicate it. I made a simple copy and paste mistake. 
The print out was done like this: `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = "AMERICAN"` when it should be `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN`.
This solved the problem with English dates transformed into Swedish dates. I guess that it should work for anyone that has a different spelling of months.

Second, To get the database to accept the time `23-APR-12 12.00.00.000000000 AM` with out generating an error was solved like this:

```
From: "CREATED" TIMESTAMP "DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM"
To:   "CREATED" TIMESTAMP "DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM"
```

### So to wrap this up.

To get English months (OCT, MAY etc) in to a non English database in a windows environment, use: `set NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN`. And the correct time format for `23-APR-12 12.00.00.000000000 AM` is `"DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM"`.

Hope this helps anyone else.